# PROBLEMA DE AUTENTICACIÓN CON PASARELA DE PAGOS STRIPE JS

Tags: javascript, stripe

soy de Colombia y me registré en Stripe poniendo como país Estados Unidos ya que Colombia no se encuentra en esa lista.

Luego intenté autenticarme como indica la documentación y resulta que siempre me arroja el siguiente error:

```
error: {
message: "You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/."
type: "invalid_request_error"
}
```

La forma en que lo estoy intentando es la siguiente:

```
 import STRIPE_KEYS from "./stripe-keys.js";
//console.log(STRIPE_KEYS);

const d = document,
  $donation = d.getElementById("donation"),
  $template = d.getElementById("donation-template") /* .content */,
  $fragment = d.createDocumentFragment(),
  fetchOptions = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer${STRIPE_KEYS.secret}`,
    },
  };

let products, prices;
Promise.all([
  fetch("https://api.stripe.com/v1/products", fetchOptions),
  fetch("https://api.stripe.com/v1/prices", fetchOptions),
])
  .then((responses) => Promise.all(responses.map((res) => res.json())))
  .then((json) => {
    console.log(json);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    let message = err.statusText || "ERROR trying to connect to STRIPE API";
    $donation.innerHTML = `<p><b>Error ${err.status}: ${message}</b></p>`;
  });
```

Sin embargo
y aunque `STRIPE_KEYS.secret` trae la clave secreta que necesito proveer en la cabecera "Authorization" me sigue arrojando el mismo error 401.
Hay alguna persona de Colombia que haya tenido éxito al autenticarse con esta API de STRIPE?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es probable que este detectando por ip que estas en un pais que no esta soportado?

Comment: @HernánGarcia lo mismo me pregunto yo

Comment: No, Stripe no filtra por dirección IP. Creo que te falta un espacio después de "Bearer": `Authorization: \`Bearer ${STRIPE_KEYS.secret}\``

Comment: @jlhonorano puedo creer lo tonto que soy, eso lo arregló todo mil gracias TE AMO EXTRAÑO :V